# RFC 4175 support in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

As of today, is [RFC 4175](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4175) (aka SMPTE 2110-20) currently supported in the released version of ffmpeg ([4.1](https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-4.1.tar.bz2))?

Surfing the web I am only able to find these two references:

- https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/patch/2701/
- https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/events/opensource17/presentations/SMPTE2110-ffmpeg.pdf

But it is not clear to me if it has been merged into the released version or not...

If so, are there some examples of `ffmpeg` / `ffplay` command lines for testing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's partially supported as of release 3.4. Added in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/01718dc0df572d2f5eebd52

Comment: Ok, thanks... Any usage example available out there?

Comment: It should be handled by the SDP or RTP demuxer.